# Property 'entries' does not exist on type ObjectConstructor

Tags: javascript

I'm using the object.entries method to push some JSON object data into an array... it was working and now I'm getting the error:

Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

I understand from looking at similar issues, this may be because the version of typescript I am using does not support the entries method, but is there an alternative? I don't feel comfortable changing versions etc as I'm new to typescript.

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                this.array.push ({
                        id: key,
                        name: value.name,
                        desc: value.desc})
            });
```

thank you for any input/help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you're using a browser that doesn't support that new-ish function, `Object.entries`

you should install the following **"polyfill"** from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
if (!Object.entries)
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
  };
```

after that code is run, `Object.entries` should be made available to your javascript runtime, it should fix the error

---

also, you could write your code this way to give a different sort of feel

```
// gather the items
const items = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
  id: key,
  name: value.name,
  desc: value.desc
}))

// append items to array
this.array = [...this.array, ...items]
```

Comment: thank you so much this works! sounds silly but i hadn't heard of polyfills before. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `"esnext"` to the `libs` in your `tsconfig.json` file, like this:

```
  "lib": ["es2018", "dom", "esnext"]
```

See [Typescript issue 30933](https://github.com/microsoft/Typescript/issues/30933#issuecomment-670569054).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "esnext" to the libs in your tsconfig.json file, like this:

```js
 "lib": ["ES2017"]
```

restart your vscode & make it take effect

maybe you also meet error

```js
Cannot find name 'setTimeout' | 'console' | 'localStorage'.
```

you can add "DOM" & "ESNext", and it will be

```js
"lib": ["ES2017", "DOM", "ESNext"],
```

Comment: I didn't need to restart. Saving tsconfig.json was sufficient.