# Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Tags: typescript

In the following I am converting an enum in to an array, it seems that I may have something missing in my tsconfig.json.

This is the script:

```
const menuItems = Object.values(MediaListFilterType).map(value => ({
    type: value,
    description: () => {
        switch (value) {
            case value === MediaListFilterType.notPitched:
                return 'Exclude already pitched';
                break;
            case value === MediaListFilterType.notDoublePitched:
                return 'Exclude double pitched';
                break;
            case value === MediaListFilterType.assignedToMe:
                return 'Assigned to me';
                break;
            case value === MediaListFilterType.notAssigned:
                return 'Unassigned';
                break;
        }
    }
}));
```

this gives me this error:
`Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.`

and the tsconfig is as follows...

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

I am a bit new at this so I am not sure what I need to change in the tsconfig. Help!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422573/property-entries-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor/45422950#45422950

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have `"target": "es2015",` but `Object.values` is not a part of es2015. Its a part of es2017 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

## Fix

Use `"target": "ESNext"` which has that feature.

Comment: -1 Target is for specifying the standard of the compiled javascript. Using `values` is a not a syntactic change. This should be configured using `lib`, specifically `es2017.object`

Answer (score 43):

add `es2017.object` to the `compilerOptions.lib` array in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: or {"compilerOptions": {"lib": ["es2017"] }

Answer (score 6):

You are calling `Object.values(...)` while targeting `es2015` (also known as ES6).
Unfortunately this feature first appears in `es2017` (also known as ES8), as you can see in the specifications for [ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), [ES7](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/), [ES8](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object.values) (first appearance of `Object.values`) or the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

The compiler adjusts itself to the target and reports to you that it doesn't know the function (in that version).

You may use a polyfill (as mentioned in the MDN article) or change TypeScript's target to `es2017` or `esnext`. If you want to let it run in a browser environment, you might have to transpile that to a lower ECMAScript version like your original target `es2015`. This can be accomplished with Babel. There are many resources on the web which show you the details (and even more lately, as Babel 7 has been released with better support for TypeScript).

By the way, this question is very similar to this ones:

- [Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959372/property-assign-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor)
- [Property 'entries' does not exist on type ObjectConstructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143348/property-entries-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor)

Answer (score 1):

for those folks who encountered this issue on their NodeJS Application, just hit `npm install` on your project, possible there is no `@types/node` or `node` installed on your app