# Accessing commands in Inquirer tool

Tags: typescript, inquirer

I installed `Inquirer` package for a command prompt tool and wrote this simple prompt:

```
function promptUser(): void {
    console.clear();
    displayTodoList(); // harmless method. 

    inquirer.prompt({
        type: "list",
        name: "command",
        message: "Choose option",
        choices: Object.values(Commands)
    }).then(answers => {
        if (answers["command"] !== Commands.Quit) {
            promptUser(); // some other harmless method.
        }
    })
}
```

But Typescript gives me compile error that `values` does not exist on type '`ObjectConstructor`' which is this line:

```
choices: Object.values(Commands)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304422/property-values-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor)

Comment: Interesting. I am targeting es2018 so yes that could be the issue.