# Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor' in Typescript Playground

Tags: typescript

Please see link. Not sure why playground is giving me this error

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=23#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIEsCmAbAJhGBeGAbwCgYyYAzEEALiMuroHIqQmYBfAGlPICMAhgCc6hGIJEwmE9h2JzioSLAgghUNFlSYc+GAApeFdNgijeZANoBrNAjrQhKMAHMAuqJg2HUJ648wjs4u3LxyAJSerD5+LlziwjHBnPgAfES8StD0rPESKQQA8nwAVmjAUAB0AG4CGACuaBD6xjoQ4ZVCmvXAaIbkBi5CIPUADhDxrdjhaRkDZCgUBlNYlawzJPPkXVD1QmD0lUdDI+N5iV5HlSdjEJUSkyZYbpwW5HJbO3sHYlc3ZwwQFg6JY-sNbmtqFhHjoXh93jwBmJWMCvG5zpJLHDeOFiLwvvs5uRooDKqp1Ppwoj+BcJGS1FBKdS5ApyRotE9mohtKZwkA

Comment: Might just be a bug in the playground app. If you change `target` to `es2017` or later it should go away, but doesn't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304422/property-values-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The availability of ECMAScript features in the standard library is governed by a compiler option called `"lib"`. As of now, you can't control `"lib"` in TypeScript Playground.

In local development, set `"lib"` to `"es2017"` or later just like Jared suggested.